# Forget Admin login/session on browser close?

Tags: admin, session, login, cookie

Is there a setting in Magento CE that will cause it to forget a user is logged into the admin  if the browser is closed (and force them to re-enter their username & password)?

e.g. for use at a shared computer and not having to rely on the user remembering to log out.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it can be done via setting cookie lifetime set to `0` from magento admin.

> System -> Configuration -> Web Tab ->Session Cookie management->Cookie Lifetime

Answer (score 0):

You can clear sessions manually in var/sessions and it should log out the logged users. If you are using someone else than files to handle sessions you might want to manually remove those too.

Comment: Thanks but what I really need is for it to automatically log out a user when they close the browser.